# Jazzcash Payment Integration V2.0

Tags: react-native, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, payment-gateway

I'm working on Rest based api version 2.0. It constantly giving me error

> Please provide a valid value for pp_SecureHash

It is working fine in case of "Page redirection" so hash key generation method is correct and issue is with parameters (maybe some missing/extra/wrong data). what I'm doing wrong?

```
{ “uri”: “https://sandbox.jazzcash.com.pk/ApplicationAPI/API/2.0/Purchase/DoMWalletTransaction”, “method”: “POST”, “body”: “pp_Amount=1100&pp_BillReference=billRef&pp_CNIC=345678&pp_Description=jazzcash&pp_Language=EN&pp_MerchantID=xyz&pp_MobileNumber=03123456789&pp_Password=xyz&pp_ReturnURL=https://sandbox.jazzcash.com.pk/ApplicationAPI/API/2.0/Purchase/DoMWalletTransaction&pp_SecureHash=BC3BABD0481A2FA756F2E16CE15FC6F8029D40E23B974065668CCEAC300B80AE&pp_TxnCurrency=PKR&pp_TxnDateTime=20220406132730&pp_TxnExpiryDateTime=20220406142730&pp_TxnRefNo=T20220406142730&ppmpf_1=1&ppmpf_2=2&ppmpf_3=3&ppmpf_4=4&ppmpf_5=5” }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `pp_SecureHash` value needs to be HmacSHA256 encoded.

```
var sHash = HMACSHA256Encode(hash, jazz.salt);
```

You can refer this code sample to achieve your requirement.

**C#:**   [Generate pp_SecureHash ()](https://github.com/saadbhatti01/Easy-System/blob/555390a51d624a95d86e2c4523d8bc6b3af21f0a/EasySystem/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L222)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your merchant Id, password and salt key. It's also through the error if your any of info is wrong.
Read the doc carefully. if add version 1.2 and in the doc it's mention 1.1 it's not going to work and through the same error. provide valid secure

If you are sure that other info is correct so you can generate secure ssh by using below method

```
$post_data =  array(
            "pp_Version"            => Config::get('constants.jazzcash.VERSION'),
            "pp_TxnType"            => "MWALLET",
            "pp_Language"           => Config::get('constants.jazzcash.LANGUAGE'),
            "pp_MerchantID"         => Config::get('constants.jazzcash.MERCHANT_ID'),
            "pp_SubMerchantID"      => "",
            "pp_Password"           => Config::get('constants.jazzcash.PASSWORD'),
            "pp_BankID"             => "TBANK",
            "pp_ProductID"          => "RETL",
            "pp_TxnRefNo"           => $pp_TxnRefNo,
            "pp_Amount"             => $pp_Amount,
            "pp_TxnCurrency"        => Config::get('constants.jazzcash.CURRENCY_CODE'),
            "pp_TxnDateTime"        => $pp_TxnDateTime,
            "pp_BillReference"      => "billRef",
            "pp_Description"        => "Description of transaction",
            "pp_TxnExpiryDateTime"  => $pp_TxnExpiryDateTime,
            "pp_ReturnURL"          => Config::get('constants.jazzcash.RETURN_URL'),
            "pp_SecureHash"         => "",
            "ppmpf_1"               => "1",
            "ppmpf_2"               => "2",
            "ppmpf_3"               => "3",
            "ppmpf_4"               => "4",
            "ppmpf_5"               => "5",
        );
```

```
    private function get_SecureHash($data_array)
    {
        ksort($data_array);
        
        $str = '';
        foreach($data_array as $key => $value){
            if(!empty($value)){
                $str = $str . '&' . $value;
            }
        }
        
        $str = Config::get('constants.jazzcash.INTEGERITY_SALT').$str;
        
        $pp_SecureHash = hash_hmac('sha256', $str, Config::get('constants.jazzcash.INTEGERITY_SALT'));
        
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($data_array);
        //echo '</pre>';
        
        return $pp_SecureHash;
    }
```

And Last by calling this method you can get the secure key

```
$pp_SecureHash = $this->get_SecureHash($post_data);
```